# Weird if condition issue in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$_SESSION['user_role'] = 1;

if ($_SESSION['user_role'] != '1' || $_SESSION['user_role'] != '2') {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Why does this if() always returns false?

Comment: Yep! There's a session_start() at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `user_role` cannot be 1 **and** 2 at the same time. Let's go through all possible values:

```
1: != 2
2: != 1
anything else: != 1, != 2
```

You probably wanted to write your condition as follows

```
if(!($_SESSION['user_role'] == 1 || $_SESSION['user_role'] == 2)) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if($_SESSION['user_role'] != 1 && $_SESSION['user_role'] != 2)) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

(boolean algebra)

Your condition can even be written without an if:

```
return $_SESSION['user_role'] == 1 || $_SESSION['user_role'] == 2;
```

PS. don't use magic values

---

For the sake of completeness, here's a truth table:

```
A := user_role == 1
B := user_role == 2

  | A | B | !B | !A | A or B | !A or !B | !(A or B) | !A and !B
--+---+---+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+-----------
1 | T | F |  T |  F |      T |        T |        F  |         F
2 | F | T |  F |  T |      T |        T |        F  |         F
--+---+---+----+----+--------+----------+-----------+-----------
3 | F | F |  T |  T |      F |        T |        T  |         T
4 | F | F |  T |  T |      F |        T |        T  |         T
5 | F | F |  T |  T |      F |        T |        T  |         T
...
```

From the table you can immediately see that `!(A or B)` is equivalent to `!A and !B`

Comment: If in doubt make the logic explicit. Cramming it all into one boolean expression causes confusion and ... this kind fo question.

Comment: Yes, but there's an "OR" not at "AND" between those two conditions. The way I read it is: if user_role is not equal to 1 or is not equal to 2 (so it can be equal to 3, 4, or any other number).

Comment: @Psyche: if it's 1, then it will satisfy the second condition (`!=2`). Same goes for 2, it will then be `!=1`. Either negate the whole expression or use `&&`/`and` (boolean algebra requires this)

Comment: better to use: ```if(($_SESSION['user_role'] == 1 || $_SESSION['user_role'] == 2)) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}``` Not nice to use negative conditions.

Comment: @Flukey: I don't use negative conditions in my last one-liner version

Comment: Indeed, the one-liner version is nice. However, I still think you should change your negative conditions in your first two examples to positive conditions. A matter of preference and readability and of course best practices ;-)

Comment: @Flukey: The OP uses negative conditions, so I only wanted to make minimal modifications to his code …

Answer (score 0):

A code for you to get it right:

```
$condition1 = ($_SESSION['user_role'] != '1');
$condition2 = ($_SESSION['user_role'] != '2');
$result     = ($condition1 || $condition2);
var_dump($condition1,$condition1,$result);
```

I am always doing this if in doubts of the result of some logical expression.

Comment: +1 Who downvoted this and didn't defend it? Seems like a legitimate debugging technique to me.

Comment: @nickb: It does not answer the question in any way. Sure, the OP will see either one of `true, false, true`, `false, true, true` and `true, true, true`, but it does not explain why this is happening and what the misunderstanding of the OP is …